# Get order info from returns

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

How can I securely validate the customer has entered the correct order ID when making a return?

At the moment I do this:

```
if ($return_info['order_id'] && $this->customer->isLogged() && $this->customer->getId() == $return_info['customer_id']) {
```

How should I do this for guest checkout when the customer is not logged in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
if ($return_info['order_id'] && 
   $this->customer->isLogged() &&
   $this->customer->getId() == $return_info['customer_id']) {
   //Condition for register user

} else if ($return_info['order_id'] && 
  !$this->customer->isLogged() && 
  $return_info['customer_id'] == 0 ){

   //Condition for guest user
}
```